# Has Dailymotion a Sandbox environment?

Tags: dailymotion-api

I was looking for this information but I did not find any.

Does Dailymotion provide a Sandbox platform while I am developing the site that uses the API's?

Thanks
Jaime

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific Dailymotion Sandbox environment, you can directly use https://www.dailymotion.com and https://api.dailymotion.com endpoints while you are developing. You can create a separate test account and if you need advanced API features on your test account, please contact our support.